# Find the value of $\int _{0} ^ {\infty} f(x+\frac1x)\frac{\ln x}{x} dx$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to find the value of the integral
$$\int _{0} ^ {\infty} f(x+\frac1x).\dfrac{\ln x}{x}.dx$$
I could not think of any idea apart from applying integration by parts but that was in vain.

Comment: Is $f$ some particular function?

Comment: I'd try substitution $t=\ln x$.

Comment: @kingW3 That doesn't makes it, seems.

Comment: What do you get?

Comment: @MPW No, it is not.

Comment: Okay, I suppose it's easy enough to show that $\int_0^1$ and $\int_1^{\infty}$ are opposites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**  Let $y:=\dfrac{1}{x}$.  Prove that the required integral, if it is integrable at all, equals
$$-\int_0^\infty\,f\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)\,\frac{\ln(y)}{y}\,\text{d}y\,.$$